# Mysql update json if-else exist

Tags: mysql, json, array

I want to update my raw with if-else condition. Here is my sql code;

```
update posts
    set like = 
      if(json_contains(like,2,'$'),
          json_remove(like,replace(json_search(like,'one',2),'"','')),
          json_array_append(like,'$',2)
        )
     where id = 3
```

My table;

| id | like |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | [] |
| 3 | [2] |

After this sql code `id= 3` should be like `id = 2`.

To sum up,: if json contain, remove from json; if json not contain, push data to array

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Maybe this the Answer:  `AUTO_INCREMENT` values do not change without explicit action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `JSON_SEARCH()` [doesn't work with integers](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79233). You must use strings.

```
mysql> set @like = '["2"]';

mysql> select if(json_contains(@like,'["2"]','$'),
  json_remove(@like,json_unquote(json_search(@like,'one','2'))),
  json_array_append(@like,'$','2')) as `like`;
+------+
| like |
+------+
| []   |
+------+

mysql> set @like = '[]';

mysql> select if(json_contains(@like,'["2"]','$'),
  json_remove(@like,json_unquote(json_search(@like,'one','2'))),
  json_array_append(@like,'$','2')) as `like`;
+-------+
| like  |
+-------+
| ["2"] |
+-------+
```

Using JSON in MySQL makes everything more difficult. I recommend instead you store your likes in a second table. Then just `INSERT` a row to add a like, or `DELETE` a row to remove a like.